# html5shiv doesn't seem to be working

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, html5shiv

Here is the current working site...
http://www.cheltenham-nursery.co.uk/building/index.html

It displays fine in IE10, but anything previous to this and the display is all over the place.

I'm loading html5shiv in the head...

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Cheltenham Nursery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/screen_styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/screen_layout_large.css" />


    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
```

Any advice or comments would be massively appreciated.

Cheers
Adam

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Instead of:

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
```

The shiv script is being recognized, but your doctype is malformed because of the white space. While newer browsers won't care, older versions of IE will render your page in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).